# Schedule a Spring batch Job to restart my application in every 4 hours

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a job in every 4 hours to restart my spring batch application in every 4 hours .I am using below code but it is only scheduling my Jobs .I have few methods that is running when application starts .Those methods are not getting scheduled

```
@EnableScheduling
public class App {
    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/4 * * * ")
    public static void restart() {
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);
        logger.info("##### Scheduler Started #####"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            logger.info("***Context Closed***"+System.currentTimeMillis());
            context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args.getSourceArgs());
            logger.info("###### Context  Restarted "+ 
            System.currentTimeMillis());
        });

        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }
 }
```

Comment: How are these methods run?

Comment: `@Scheduled` on `static` methods won't work. Also why restart your application every 4 hours? Seems like a fix/solution for something that should be fixed differently.

Comment: @ M. Deinum  :I have a method (Where i am calling a Powershell script which is returning a JSON file that i am using in my Steps. As the method is called in Constructor so it is getting called when bean is initialized.So i have to restart my application everytime

Comment: @Simon Martinelli : The main method is getting called when i right clik->Run ->SpringBoot Application and subsequent call is happening based on scheduled time.

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum, this should be fixed differently. I added an answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum I removed static from the restart() method. Now it is scheduling properly to restart my application in specified time provided in cron expression. Just to know : How we can define/call class level variables using Spring Batch.

Answer (score 0):

> As the method is called in Constructor so it is getting called when bean is initialized.So i have to restart my application everytime

You don't need to close/restart the application context at each schedule for this. You can move any  initialzation code in a `JobExecutionListener#beforeJob` which is more appropriate for your use case.

Another way to address this is by creating a tasklet that calls the script that generates the json file (a `SystemCommandTasklet` for instance), then create a second step that reads the file with a json item reader (the file name could be shared between both steps through the execution context).

In both cases, there is no need to close/restart the application context at each schedule as you currently do.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud :I did in that way but i have again a list that is defined on class level which is reading the JSON file that Powershell script is generating .If i am writing that method inside JobExecutionListener#beforeJob .That List is getting called first and the method that i am writing inside JobExecutionListener#beforeJob  is called after that .So my application always reading the older JSON file.

Comment: Looks like you should rather be using a dedicated `ItemReader` for this. Also `beforeJob` is always called before the execution so it should always update the holding list (although it feels like you are keeping state in the wrong place).

Comment: You should not use global state for that. Since you want to read the new file on each run, move that list as a local variable to the method (and I don't see why it is a list btw).

Comment: @Mahmoud If i am adding the List inside read() method of ItemReader each time it is calling the JSON file for every single record comes in the Reader. As i am using Chunk based Step. Also how can i use SystemCommandTasklet to call a PowerShell Script ,Is there any example to refer .

Comment: My answer is about the `JobExecutionListener#beforeJob` method, so you should put the list as a local variable in the `JobExecutionListener#beforeJob` method, not the `read` method of the reader. For the system command tasklet, you can find examples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTaskletIntegrationTests.java.

Comment: Inside my beforeJob method i have a single call ULProspectorAPICall.runShellScript(); runShellScript() will run the ShellScript and give me a JSON file in specified path.2) Aftrer the JSON is created Then on My ItemReader i am reading the JSON file for which i have declared a List which is reading the JSON object and storing in List of POJO Object .For the 2nd step i have created a List in class level in ItemReader class.

Comment: Well that's exactly what we are trying to tell you to do differently. Do not share data using a global state in a list like that. You can share the file name between the listener and the json reader using the execution context. And as mentioned in the answer, another approach is to use a different step and share the file name between both steps through the execution context as well.

Comment: @Mahmoud : Can you please tell me an example .I have the List like this         
                           List<Data> ulpData = ReadJSONFromULP.getJsonObject();         where ReadJSONFromULP is a plain java class to convert JSONObject to List of POJO objects. Please let me know in example how you want me to call my JSON file